# passing parameter values to stored procedure when calling from another procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure sp1 which takes parameters @id int, @type int, @ orderno int

Now, I am trying to call sp1 from sp2

```
alter proc sp2
/insert into @temp_tbl exec sp1 1,2,3
set @select = 'select * from @temp_tbl'  --@select is already declared
exec (@select)
```

Now when I try to call my sp2

```
exec sp2
```

I get the error: procedure or function 'sp1' expects parameter @id, which was not supplied. so, how do I pass the parameters??

Comment: The same way you do it from outside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as,for example:

```
insert into @temp_tbl exec sp1 @id=1, @type=2, @orderno=3
```

but you obviously need the values to pass (which could come from other parameters, etc).

```
DECLARE @OrderNoSource INT = 33;
insert into @temp_tbl exec sp1 @id=1, @type=2, @orderno=@OrderNoSource;
```

So, a more complete example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
GO -- necessary to define the fake sp1 for this script
create procedure sp1 @id int, @type int, @orderno int as SELECT @id, @type, @orderno ;
GO
declare @temp_tbl TABLE (id int, [type] int, orderno int);

insert into @temp_tbl EXEC sp1 1,2,3

SELECT * FROM @temp_tbl; -- this works, no EXEC() needed!

DECLARE @select VARCHAR(MAX); 
SET @select = 'SELECT * FROM @temp_tbl;'
EXEC (@select);  -- FAILS: @temp_tbl is a VARIABLE and NOT IN SCOPE!;

SELECT * INTO  #temp_tbl FROM @temp_tbl ; -- copy local TABLE VAR to TEMP Table (stored in temp db, private)
SET @select = 'SELECT * FROM #temp_tbl;' -- note @ changed to #
EXEC (@select); -- This also works, because temp table are in scope

ROLLBACK -- cleanup this test
```

Comment: did I do something wrong here: after I did insert into temp_tbl exec sp1 1,2,2 --> set @select = 'select * from temp_tbl' --> exec(select)...End

Comment: @user3399326: I have expanded the answer.  TABLE variables are limited in SCOPE and are not accessible to EXEC().  But you really don't need (or want) to do an EXEC() in this scenario.  Perhaps you should refine your question

Comment: thnks Stan it was really helpful